# How to Remove Random Text Breaks in HTML Text

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape some of the text out of a couple HTML documents, but I can't get rid of some of the line breaks. Currently I have Beautiful Soup parsing the web pages, then I read in all the lines and attempt to strip all the newline characters out of the text, but I can't get rid of the ones in the middle of strings. For example,

```
<font face="ARIAL" size="2">Thomas
H. Lenagh </font>
```

I'm looking to get the name of this person out on one line, but there is a newline character of some sort in the middle. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
line=line.replace("\n"," ")
line=line.replace("\\n"," ")
line=line.replace("\r\n", " ")
line=line.replace("\t", " ")
line=line.replace("\\r\\n"," ")
```

I've also tried the following regex expressions:

```
line=re.sub("\n"," ",line)
line=re.sub("\\n", " ",line)
line=re.sub("\s\s+", " ",line)
```

None have worked so far and I'm not sure what character I'm missing. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the full code that I'm using (minus error checking):

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(threePage) #make the soup
paragraph=soup.stripped_strings
if paragraph is not None: 
for i in range (len(data)): #for all rows...
    lineCounter=lineCounter+1
    row =data[i]
    row=row.replace("\n"," ") #remove newline (<enter>) characters
    row = re.sub("---+"," ",row) #remove dashed lines
    row =re.sub(","," ",row) #replace commas with spaces
    row=re.sub("\s\s+", " ",row) #remove 
    if ("/s/" in row): #if /s/ is in the row, remove it
         row=re.sub(".*/s/"," ",row)
    if ("/S/" in row): #upper case of the last removal
         row=re.sub(".*/S/"," ",row)
    row = row.replace("\n"," ")
    row=row.strip()#remove any weird characters
```

Comment: What does the output look like if you do `print(repr(line))` before doing any replaces?

Comment: Are newlines important to you? If there are no sections wrapped in <pre>...</pre> (or similar), then you can simply replace all newlines with spaces, because that's what the HTML rendering engine does.

Comment: @PeterRowell  I'm sending the information I pull from the documents into a comma delimited, single line of text for another part of my program.... so getting rid of them is a must :)

Comment: @Kevin when I use the print(repr(line)), it prints out \n characters in the line of text.

Comment: is `row = row.strip()` the very last line in your `for` loop? Note that strings are immutable, and assigning new values to `row` won't change what's being stored in `data`.

Comment: Ahhhhh.... right. Yep, I just threw the lines back into the list and now it works.... thanks so much for noticing the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared what the rest of your code looks like after the `for` loop, but I'm guessing a very simplified version is something like:

```
data = ["a\nb", "c\nd", "e\nf"]

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i]
    row = row.replace("\n", "")

#let's see if that fixed it...    
print(data)
#output: ['a\nb', 'c\nd', 'e\nf']
#hey, the newlines are still there! What gives?
```

This occurs because calling `replace` on a string doesn't mutate it in-place, and assigning new values to `row` doesn't change what values are being stored in `data`. If you want `data` to be changed too, you've got to assign the values back.

```
data = ["a\nb", "c\nd", "e\nf"]

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i]
    row = row.replace("\n", "")
    data[i] = row

#let's see if that fixed it...    
print data
#output: ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
#looking good!
```

---

Bonus style tip: if your replacement logic is simple enough to express in one expression, you can get it all on one line and avoid messing around with `range` and indices etc:

`data = [row.replace("\n", "") for row in data]`